# How to denote common class names with slight numeral changes into one - CSS shorthand?

Tags: css

I'm trying Bootstrap, and came into a question, though the question is regarding CSS:

```
.span1,
.span2,
.span3,
.span4,
.span5,
.span6,
.span7,
.span8,
.span9,
.span10,
.span11,
.span12{
    border: 1px dashed #CCC;
    }
```

To do border to all types of `.span#`, I did the CSS mentioned above. Is there any way I can denote it by:

```
.span1 - .span12{
    border: 1px dashed #CCC;
    }
```

Is it possible using CSS?

Comment: Can you not just give them all a comment class?

Comment: You could also switch to using SASS or LESS...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
span[class^="span"]
{
    border: 1px dashed #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/K3693/1476/)

---

If they were all going to start with the class 'span' and end differently, something like this will work - `span[class^='span']`.

Here's the example from the jsFiddle:

**CSS:**

```
span[class^='span'] { border: 1px dashed #CCC; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="span1">Example</span> 
<span class="span2">Example</span> 
<span class="ddf">Example</span> 
<span class="span4">Example</span> 
<span class="dddf">Example</span> 
<span class="span6">Example</span> 
<span class="span7">Example</span> 
<span class="span8">Example</span>
```

Comment: As far as I know, it `*=` means 'contains' not 'starts with'. `^=` means 'starts with' ;)

Comment: I know both worked, but the former would work for `<span class="99span">Example</span>` aswell ;)

Comment: @MythThrazz Of course, but the other answer was originally `div[class^="span"]` (before 5 minute edit) but no one pointed that out..